# Why does the SQL return different result while using count and count,* in query

Tags: sql

I have tables `attendance`, `employee`, `payroll`

**Attendance** table:

```
Employee_ID  Clockin    Clockout
---------------------------------
1            08:00:00    18:00:00
2            08:00:00    18:00:00
3            08:00:00    18:00:00
4            08:00:00    18:00:00
```

**Employee** table:

```
Employee_ID   Name       Employee_type
---------------------------------
1            Mary         Full-time
2            Peter        Full-time
3            John         Full-time
4            Henry        Full-time
```

This is the SQL query that I get only 1 row

```
    SELECT *, COUNT(attendance.Clockin)
    FROM payroll
    LEFT JOIN attendance ON attendance.Employee_ID = payroll.Employee_ID
    LEFT JOIN employee ON employee.Employee_ID = payroll.Employee_ID
    WHERE employee.Employee_type = 'Full-time'
```

Here is the SQL query that I get more rows returned

```
    SELECT *
    FROM payroll
    LEFT JOIN attendance ON attendance.Employee_ID = payroll.Employee_ID
    LEFT JOIN employee ON employee.Employee_ID = payroll.Employee_ID
    WHERE employee.Employee_type = 'Full-time'
```

What's the difference between these two queries?

Comment: Assuming this is mysql, it uses an extended group by.  Meaning, if you don't define the group by it will pick a single value from each column and return it.  Since the first has an aggregate the extended group by is in effect, where as the second select * has no aggregate so it simply returns every row.  [The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: The result set's attendance.Clockin contain null's.

Comment: You are selecting from `payroll` table. Where is it? Show it's content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce3e30/3/0)

The above fiddle has 3 different queries;  I extended your 1st query to show what happens in mysql when you don't have a group by.

Consider:

```
--Yours without a group by, you get one row.  This is due to mySQL "Extended" group by  
SELECT *, COUNT(attendance.Clockin)
FROM payroll
LEFT JOIN attendance
ON attendance.Employee_ID = payroll.Employee_ID
LEFT JOIN employee
ON employee.Employee_ID = payroll.Employee_ID
WHERE employee.Employee_type = 'Full-time';

--Mine, with a group by, you get multiple rows
SELECT *, COUNT(attendance.Clockin)
FROM payroll P
LEFT JOIN attendance
ON attendance.Employee_ID = P.Employee_ID
LEFT JOIN employee
ON employee.Employee_ID = P.Employee_ID
WHERE employee.Employee_type = 'Full-time'
GROUP BY P.Employee_ID, clockin, clockout, employee_Type;

SELECT *
FROM payroll
LEFT JOIN attendance
ON attendance.Employee_ID = payroll.Employee_ID
LEFT JOIN employee
ON employee.Employee_ID = payroll.Employee_ID
WHERE employee.Employee_type = 'Full-time';
```

Simply put if you don't define the group by the mySQL DB engine will pick a single value from each column and return it. Since the first SQL statmeent has an aggregate, the extended group by is in effect; whereas the second SQL has no aggregate so it simply returns every row. 
[From mySQL docs: The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: By the way, I want to know what's the difference between the query between mySQL and other sql such as the microsoft one?

Comment: MySQL, to my knowledge, is the only engine which has this extended use of group by enabled by default.  This feature can be disabled.  DB2/ SQL Server, oracle, PostgreSQL I believe all support the standard use of the GROUP BY without the extension.  Each engine supports it's own "Flavor" of SQL.  Most have the basic constructs the same, but all vary on use of built in functions.  There's no one silver bullet when it comes to what works and doesn't work in each engine.  your basic SELECT, FROM, WHERE are about all that I can say are truly consistent.  Date logic, substring, group by... can vary

Answer (score 1):

Oops, that is MySQL, isn't it?

With

```
COUNT(attendance.Clockin)
```

you aggregate data. There is no GROUP BY clause, so you get only one row returned.

As to:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(attendance.Clockin)
```

, this is not allowed by standard SQL, because you select columns that are not unique for the aggregation. For example there are many names, so what name to show in that one returned row? MySQL has solved it such that it returns one of the names available arbitrarily.

With

```
SELECT *
```

however, you are not aggregating your rows. You show them as they are.